# How can I use input data from form by using TemplateView

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I am trying to create a simulation site which shows the results of calculation and graph by inputing figures.
Because I need to integrate a graph created by plotly, my views.py looks like this:

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.shortcuts import redirect
import pandas as pd
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

    from . import plots
    class ScatterView(TemplateView):
        template_name='simulator.html'
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(ScatterView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['scatter'] = plots.get_scatter()
            return context
```

The graph can successfully be shown now, but how can I use data input from the form of simulator.html?
There are many explanations on web but they are mostly function based like

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

but how can I do that by class based?

**simulator.html:**

the data to be used are for example 'Century', 2019

```
<form method='POST' action=''>{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for='input_model_name' class="control-label">Name of Model</label>
      <select name='model_name' placeholder='model_name' class="form-control">
        <option>------</option>
        <option>Century</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for='input_model_year' class="control-label">Model_Year</label>
      <input type='integer' name='model_year' placeholder="model_year" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" name="calculation">calculate</button>
    <p></p>
    <div class="form-group">
  </form>
```

What I finally want to do is assign the input data to below 'submit_model_name' and 'submit_model_year', so that further calculation can be done.

**plots.py:**

```
import pandas as pd
import os

def get_submit_data():
    submit_model_name = 'Century'  <= how can I assign input data?
    submit_model_year=2015  <= how can I assign input data?
    return submit_model_name, submit_model_year

def get_database():
    model_name = get_submit_data()[0]
    df=pd.read_csv("database1.csv")
    df=df.query("model==@model_name")
    return df

def get_price():
    df=get_database()
    input_model_year=get_submit_data()[1]
```

**urls.py in app folder:**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import signupfunc, loginfunc
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from .views import ScatterView

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', signupfunc, name='signup'),
    path('login/', loginfunc, name='login'),
    path('simulator/', ScatterView.as_view(), name='simulator'),
]
```

Comment: instead of using class TemplateView use class View. Please read this documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/ . It is well described with examples :)

Comment: Thanks, I am now reading... if any specific advice, please let me know, anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: If you're form is just used to filter or query data, it may make more sense to use a `GET` request? Then override the `get_context_data()` method of the view to perform the query, and put the results in the context?

Comment: @AKN As I said at begin - use View class. Then you have to override method `def get...` to hold GET requests, for rendering form. Then you have to override method `def post...`. Here in method `post`, you have data from your form.

Comment: @404pio thanks, but as I just changed TemplateView to View class, runserver caused error with the message Method Not Allowed (GET): /simulator/
Method Not Allowed: /simulator/

Comment: When you changed TemplateView to View, have you write method `get` in your class?

Comment: @404pio No, I don't get what you mean with get method here.What does it exactly look like?

Comment: What shall I write if I want for example <input name='model_year' placeholder="model_year"> on simulator.html ?

Comment: @404pio why are you giving this advice? OP wants to process a form; he should use a FormView. There is no difference between View and TemplateView except that TemplateView renders a template, which is what OP wants.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm giving advice of using just View, because imho it is easy to understand for novice django developers(AKN, do not know what is get method of TemplateView/View). You are right about the difference, but it is more complicated.

Comment: @AKN try to write your ScatterView as a classical method view, then you can place `if request.method == POST`, where you can read data from html form.

Comment: Thanks both gentlemen, I’ll try tomorrow. Really appreciate!